GIGA IDE при запуске выдаёт ошибку. Как исправить?
Ошибка заключается в том, что Microsoft Defender замедляет работу GIGA IDE.


Если нажимаю кнопку

Automatically

то появляется следующее сообщение

Если вручную делаю настройки, которые указаны, то при запуски также появляется данное сообщение об ошибке.

От админа её запусти - может получится.
